# DevExpress AspxGridView Row Editing Event

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I am using DevExpress GridView and I am showing

```
<EditButton Visible="True"></EditButton>
```

Now,I want to show my Custom `PopUpControl` on `EditButton` Click.
I am unable to find the Event which fires on `EditButton` Click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Edit button](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewCommandColumn_EditButtontopic) switches the ASPxGridView to edit mode. There is no explicit `Click` event for this button.
Take a look at [Grid Editing - Edit Form Template](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditFormTemplate.aspx) demo to learn how to provide any possible layout for GridView's Edit Form using the appropriate template.